# How do I use an enum in Flutter to define names for selectedIndex that synchs with destinations

Tags: flutter, dart, selectedindex

I'd like to define an enum (or something) to give names to possible values of seletedIndex and define the order of destinations in, say, a Flutter NavigationBar in such a way that I only have to go to one place to change the order of the destinations.

The examples I've seen so far always require reordering be done in two places: one in the list of destinations given to the NavigationBar that have an implicit, invisible, unnamed index, and the other is a switch or a subscripting based on selectedIndex to establish the selected page.  This seems like a bug magnet. Is there any way to set it up so I only define the order of the destinations in one place and have the list of destinations bound to the correct pages?

It seems to me that NavigationDestination should have a property to handle this binding or a "displayOrder" property, but I don't see this. If there isn't a better way, I guess I could write a function to construct the destination list based on an object (like an enum) that binds the numeric indicies to the corresponding page view, but this seems like a lot of machinery to create for a routine navbar task, especially in this modern OO context --  weird that selecting navbar pages would need a switch in the switchless programming world. Yet the example implementations have switches and two separate areas of the code need to be maintained to do one thing.  But, what do I know; obligatory newbie disclaimer follows...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Anyone who could understand the question I'm asking wouldn't need to see any code.

Answer (score 0):

I think my question above was poorly phrased, based on ignorance and seeing some naive examples that suggested page navigation was generally done with an integer like selectedIndex. Once I learned about the Navigator class, and other navigation and List related builders, I saw the OO techniques Flutter provides for putting together hierarchical menus and such without the use of switch statements and integer indicies. So my answer to somebody like me who asks "do I really need to re-invent the navigation wheel" is to learn about [Navigation Basics](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).